# Is altering a function argument inside the function bad style?

Tags: typescript

Today the following code of mine was critcized as being bad style:

```
export const myFunction = (myArgument: TypeOfObject[]) => {
  if (!myArgument) {
    myArgument = [];
  }
  // do something with myArgument
}
```

This is TypeScript, so to the best of my knowledge the following is happening: `myFunction` is getting passed by value a pointer called `myArgument`. If that pointer is pointing to `undefined`, I re-point it to `[]`, otherwise I leave it as it is. So neither am I changing the object that it is pointing to nor am I changing the pointer itself for the context of the caller.

This has been criticized as bad style with the explanation that the function argument should not be altered. The following alternative has been suggested:

```
export const myFunction = (myArgument: TypeOfObject[]) => {
  let myArgumentSecond: TypeOfObject[];
  if (!myArgument) {
    myArgumentSecond = [];
  } else {
    myArgumentSecond = [...myArgument];
  }

  // do something with myArgumentSecond (instead of with myArgument)
}
```

What is your opinion on this? Is the second version really better?

Note that while this is TypeScript here, I think this is really a general programming question and I fail to understand what is supposed to be wrong with the first version.

Comment: What is `TypeOfObject` and what is the "something" you're doing afterward?  Without knowing these I can't really say much about whether or not this is good or bad.  And if you're using `--strictNullChecks` (which you should be using) then there's no reason to check `myArgument` for truthiness.  Is `myArgument` supposed to be optional?

Comment: Finally: if this question is truly just about style and you are explicitly asking for opinions, it will probably be closed as subjective.  Stack Overflow is meant for questions with authoritative answers, [not](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for code review or eliciting opinions.

Comment: @jcalz TypeOfObject is just an interface like `{name: string, value: string}`. "something" is just reading from `myArgument`. And let's say I cannot control the calling of the function, but `myArgument` can come in as undefined.

Comment: Could you [edit] the code in the question to be a [mre] so that when I paste it into an IDE like The TypeScript Playground it demonstrates something without unrelated errors?  If `TypeOfObject` can be defined as you mentioned for the example, then let's do that.  If you can pass in `undefined` then `myArgument` should be optional or otherwise include `undefined`.  Like [this perhaps](https://tsplay.dev/mbQ8BN)?

Comment: Sorry to be repetitive, but it doesn't look like you addressed these: • Could you please clarify what "do something with `myArgument`" entails?  If that is something which could possibly modify the array, then there's more than just a stylistic difference between the two versions.  • Questions inviting opinions and not facts are generally closed as too subjective; could you edit the question to ask something for which it is possible to find an objective answer?

Comment: This is ultimately an opinion-based question, though the suggested alternative seems like a straw man argument. The closer equivalent alternative would be `const myArgumentSecond = myArgument || [];`, which has the same behaviour as the original code, or you could use `??` if it is only null/undefined that you want to coalesce.

Comment: Another point: if the function is not supposed to mutate the array, it should be declared as `readonly TypeOfObject[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// If you are using this in a purely TypeScript project, that should be
// default argument value

export const myFunction1 = (myArgument: TypeOfObject[] = []) => {
  // do something with myArgument
  myArgument
  // ^? (parameter) myArgument: TypeOfObject[]
}
// because function doesn't say it can be called with non-array.

// If it can be called with non-array, it should say so
export const myFunction2 = (myArgument?: TypeOfObject[] | null | undefined) => {
  myArgument ??= [];
  myArgument
  // ^? (parameter) myArgument: TypeOfObject[]
}

// if you use type-casting you SHOULD use another variable as TypeScript doesn't handle them
export const myFunction3 = (a: number | string) => {
  a = Number(a) % 3 as 0 | 1 | 2
  ;; a
  // ^? (parameter) a: number
  let b = Number(a) % 3 as 0 | 1 | 2
  //  ^? let b: 0 | 1 | 2
}

interface TypeOfObject {};
```

---

If someone wants to prevent the argument assignement, they should use
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-param-reassign
rule. If the linter says you shouldn't change arguments, then you shouldn't. If the linter doesn't say that, then you generally can.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that down. I agree, this is how it should be done in TypeScript to make it perfectly clear what's expected and allowed as argument to the function. The main point of my question was more about (regardless of the programming language) the general concept of altering an argument inside a function which to my understanding is prefectly fine in a call by value context. So as far as I understand your `myFunction2` is the equivalent of my code, but with a better (fully complete) function declaration.

Comment: @user1195883 added more info on enforcing the rule

Comment: Thanks, very interesting that eslint has a config for that!

Comment: @user1195883 if you are interested in lint configs, check `xo`, it includes most of the modern ones

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key difference between your code and the suggestion is that you are guarenteed to never *mutate* the argument. That is, whatever argument you send to the function is guaranteed to never be *changed* (in a shallow sense, as you can still change the items inside the array). Whether or not one or the other is better is a matter of discussion and intent. For example:

```js
function sortInplace(x) { // Displays intent that you want to mutate 
  x.sort()
}

function sortNotInplace(x) {
  return [...x].sort()
}

a = [4,3,2,1]

sortInplace(a) // mutates 'a', this function is impure

console.log(a) // [1,2,3,4]

b = [4,3,2,1]
c = sortNotInplace(b) // copies 'b' then sorts the copy, and returns the sorted copy, function is pure

console.log(b) // [4,3,2,1]
console.log(c) // [1,2,3,4]
```

It is often nice to have functions that are "pure", meaning they never change anything "on the outside", as the opposed "impure" functions can cause hard to find bugs.

The cost of purity is usually runtime performance as you generally have to do more copying, although you can often get by with very little performance penalty in many cases. The suggested code will create an entirely new array. If your input array is large, then the computer has to, well, create an entirely new large array, which can be inefficient.

**This is only my opinion, which may or may not fit for whomever reads this**:

I believe your first snippet is fine (it is what I would prefer), the most important thing is that you are always *aware* whether you are mutating the input or not, then properly signalling that it will mutate the input if that is the case (or change the function if mutation is undesired). It is also worthwhile to consider whether your peers have agreed on a coding style. If the suggested code is what your peers have agreed to then I would say you should follow that (this is most relevant for a software team). The suggested code makes it extremely obvious that the input array won't be changed (but then again, if the function is small and easy to read it may be obvious anyways).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. I agree with everything that you've written and as @kaya3 has pointed out in the comments above, the suggested code seems like a straw man argument because it doesn't even pull a full deep copy. So it's just a more complicated code that actually is not different except for the imho pointless shallow copy which does not guarantee that the objects inside the array are not going to be changed.